# Multitrack video export in OBS Studio

Tags: compositing, obs

OBS Studio composites various video inputs into a single video stream, but it lets users configure local recording on the side. Is it possible to save each video input separately, preferably as multiple channels within the same file or alternatively as separate files? I see multitrack audio options but am not sure whether the live export option only works for the composite video stream.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for the same answer and found a [thread in the OBS forum](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/can-obs-record-multiple-video-tracks.52690/).

OBS does not support multitrack video support yet. The thread contains two workarounds:

## Run two instances of OBS simultaneously

[Directlink to post in thread](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/can-obs-record-multiple-video-tracks.52690/post-244778)

1. Open OBS Studio.
2. Sitting > hotkeys > Gave Start recording and Stop recording nice Hotkey (I use Ctrl+Shift+S and Ctrl+Shift+D)
3. Close then Open OBS Studio.
4. Open OBS Studio Again (Now you have 2 OBS Studio)
5. in the first OBS Go to sitting > Output > Recording > Select recording path
6. in the 2nd OBS Go to sitting > Output > Recording > Select recording path "Gave it another name"
   Ex : Rec\FaceCame and Rec\GamePlay
7. Start the game and press Ctrl+Shift+S or the hotkey you pick

Drawbacks: A lot of manual steps to execute.

## Increase the canvas size, place multiple videos side by side on it and split it in a video software afterwards

[Directlink to post in thread](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/can-obs-record-multiple-video-tracks.52690/post-363617)

Drawbacks: No usable video output during recording.